# codeigniter multiple applications, with wild card sub domains, mod_rewrite remapping sub domains to .php

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a codeigniter project structured as so:

```
httpdocs/
  /application/
    /ggg/
      config/
      controllers/
      models/
      libraries/
      views/
      ...
    /sgaz/
      config/
      controllers/
      models/
      libraries/
      views/
      ...
    /index/
      config/
      controllers/
      models/
      libraries/
      views/
      ...
  /system/
  index.php
```

I am trying to re write a wildcard sub domain to map to its respective application.. Just not sure how to go about this.

I know you can create multiple applications and use multiple (.*).php files for each application (IE: ggg.php, sgaz.php, index.php). But Is it possible have a single index.php file and use mod_rewrite to redirect calls from a sub domain to its respective application env? IE: http://ggg.mapitusa.com/user/login redirects (without htaccess) to http://mapitusa.com/index.php/ggg/user/login?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.mapitusa\.com$ [NC] 
#if not existing file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#rewrite to index.php
RewriteRule ^ index.php/%1%REQUEST_URI] [L]
```

If you want the URL in the address bar to change to `http://mapitusa.com/index.php/ggg/user/login?`, replace the RewriteRule above with

```
RewriteRule ^ http://mapitusa.com/index.php/%1%REQUEST_URI] [L,R=301]
```