# Is creation of subdomain the only way?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-url

Im using CodeIgniter and I want to create a site in which many (about a  thousand) users can register and do things.

Each user will have their own gallery, an about page etc.

What I want to achieve is that as the user login using password the url should show

```
user_name.domain.com
```

Do I really need to create subdomain for each user  to achieve this
(The folder structure doesn't really made  for the subdomain way and I am halfway through the project.So i would really appreciate other alternative (s,(if any))

Or

Can I achieve the same using htaccess rewrite url rule?

Comment: I would simply use a wildcard `*.yourdomain.com` and handle it on the php side.

Comment: but wildcard is subdomain creation right? and I need it dynamically.Will not the folder structure  a problem if I use subdomain (ie each user files should be placed in separate folders.Is n't it??

Comment: Yes, but you only have to do it once and after you have setup the wildcard you don't have to ever look at it again. And no you can setup apache to handle all subdomains and let it look in the same directory structure for all domains.

Comment: thank you for your fast replies.Let me do that

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a php script that can host sub domains dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20720447/how-to-make-a-php-script-that-can-host-sub-domains-dynamically)

Answer (score -1):

As PeeHaa pointed out you should use wildcards.

There's another stackoverflow thread covering the problem: [codeigniter multiple applications, with wild card sub domains, mod_rewrite remapping sub domains to .php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287025/codeigniter-multiple-applications-with-wild-card-sub-domains-mod-rewrite-remap)

Comment: Please post at least the gist of the answer here. Just linking to other sites which (may) contain the answer is frowned upon, since links age and may eventually disappear, leaving this answer useless.